# extjs ajax store running slow

Tags: ajax, extjs

I don't come to stackoverflow much unless I'm really stumped.   I took over a code base from a guy that always used this extjs.  I understand it and can build on it but for some reason this one ajax call runs very slow, but when put in a normal ajax jquery or a MySQL query it does not run slow.

when I analyse all the code of the get-list function and the model it's calling, they all run fine with each other.  It's only when it comes from this extjs store does it run twice as slow?

here's the code:

```
store: {
    autoLoad: true,
    model: "User",
    pageSize: 50,
    remoteSort: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: '/admin/users/get-list',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'rows'
        },
        actionMethods: {
            create: 'POST',
            read: 'POST',
            update: 'POST',
            destroy: 'POST'
        }
    }
}
```

Are there any extjs experts out there that would know why this call runs twice as long as just calling the function normally?

Comment: There are so many possible reasons. Please setup a fiddle with the view, controller and viewModel, so that we can help. Are there any listeners on the store or grid. Did you override functionality for the stores (seems that the url might not be complete). Is the call exactly the same for Extjs as for jquery? Does the backend understand pageSize 50 .... Just not enough information

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Sorry I took pto the day after I asked this question and did not receive an answer.  I'll see if I can make a fiddle and make it more clear today at some point.

Comment: :thumbsup: yes please